# print nullable type on Razor Template Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nullable, razor

I want print "null" if model field is null.
My field

```
public int? PostHouseNumber { get; set; }
```

In cshtml

```
@(item.PostHouseNumber == null ? "null" : item.PostHouseNumber)
```

How to cast int? to string ?

Comment: You can always do "" + intValue to cast to a string as well as bobby's suggestion of .ToString()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`item.PostHouseNumber.Value.ToString()`

Comment: This will throw object null reference exception if item.PostHouseNumber is null.

Comment: @mlienau is ~right. (For my version of razor MVC etc) I get a runtime exception : System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

Answer (score 5):

OK here is the peice. any nullable type remember two properties
1. HasValue
2. Value :)

so your check will be

```
@(item.PostHouseNumber.HasValue ? item.PostHouseNumber.Value.ToString() : "null")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@(item.PostHouseNumber.HasValue ? item.PostHouseNumber.ToString() : "null")
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on previous answer(s) (just a stylistic choice)

```
@(item.PostHouseNumber != null? item.PostHouseNumber.ToString() : "null")
```